# Windows UI Application automation TestStack(White) GetWindow not working

Tags: c#, white-framework

Windows UI Application automation TestStack(White) GetWindow not working and gives exception always.

***Please tell me what I am missing.***

- .NET 4.5.2 TestS
- tack.White 0.13.3

---

```
void Test()
{
    Application calcApp = null;
    Window calcWindow = null;
    calcApp = Application.Launch("calc.exe");
    var MainWindowTitle = "Calculator";
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40 * 1000);
    // calcWindow = calcApp.GetWindow("Calculator", InitializeOption.NoCache); Not Working
    calcWindow = Retry.For(() => calcApp.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByText(MainWindowTitle), InitializeOption.NoCache), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
    Console.WriteLine("End test");
}
```

Exception::

> Message=Couldn't find window with SearchCriteria Name=Calculator in
>   process 8292, after waiting for 5000 ms Source=TestStack.White
>   StackTrace:   at
>   TestStack.White.Factory.ChildWindowFactory.WaitTillFound(Func`1 find,
>   String message) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\89a20b30302799e\src\TestStack.White\Factory\ChildWindowFactory.cs:line
>   43    at
>   TestStack.White.Factory.WindowFactory.CreateWindow(SearchCriteria
>   searchCriteria, Process process, InitializeOption option,
>   WindowSession windowSession) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\89a20b30302799e\src\TestStack.White\Factory\WindowFactory.cs:line
>   83    at TestStack.White.Application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria
>   searchCriteria, InitializeOption initializeOption) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\89a20b30302799e\src\TestStack.White\Application.cs:line
>   205   at
>   Calculator_Automation.Program.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<StartCalcTest>b__0()
>   in E:\YogeshWork\ProjectWork\Win App Automation\Calculator
>   Automation\Calculator Automation\Program.cs:line 53   at
>   TestStack.White.Utility.Retry.For[T](Func`1 getMethod, Predicate`1
>   shouldRetry, TimeSpan retryFor, Nullable`1 retryInterval) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\89a20b30302799e\src\TestStack.White\Utility\Retry.cs:line
>   138   at TestStack.White.Utility.Retry.For[T](Func`1 getMethod,
>   TimeSpan retryFor, Nullable`1 retryInterval) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\89a20b30302799e\src\TestStack.White\Utility\Retry.cs:line
>   95

**P.S.**
For "Calculator" app on Windows 10 White framework fails to get Main Window handle. Anyone has idea why this is not working ?

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine on my PC, including the commented out line.  Are you compiling for x86?

Comment: @LordWilmore, I am using Windows 10. After posting query I have tested it on Windows 7 and 8 that works fine. But for Win 10 it does not works. Which version of OS do you have?

Comment: Sorry to come back late to this.  Yes I am running Windows 7.  I'd recommend re-posting this with a simpler description, e.g. GetWindow() not working on Windows 10.

Comment: @GMCSPune Did you make any progress with this/find a work around for Windows 10?